# How to install a rtl8192fu usb wireless adapter

Tags: 18.04

i have a tp-link rtl8192fu wireless usb adapter vid:pid is 2357:0135
i find a rtl8192eu driver at github, but it can not work.
Is anyone tell me how to resolve it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

follow this:

https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8192fu-dkms

After rebooting, if you can't find the device, check the information with 'dmest | less'

Comment: You should provide installation details directly in your answer.